# Motivation for the name "vertical subspace" in the context of fiber bundles.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, intuition, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $p:E\to B$ be a smooth fiber bundle with fiber $F$. Consider the vector spaces $V_u=\{x\in T_uE: p_*(x)=0\}$. We call $V_u$ the vertical subspace of the tangent space $T_uE$.

How can we see that $V_u$ is the tangent space to $E_u$, the fiber over $u$? What is the intuition to call them vertical?

How does $T_uE_u$ sit in $T_uE$? Do we speak of $T_uE_u$'s that are close together? How does $T_uE_u$ sit against $T_vE_v$? Which are the transition maps for the subbundle $\cup_u T_uE_u$? Which is its topology?

**Thought:** If $E$ is a principle $F$-bundle, and the Lie algebra of $F$ is $\mathfrak{f}$, we can identify $V_u$ with $\mathfrak{f}$. In this situation we partially answered the first question. Despite having an identification I do not see that $V_u$ is tangent to $E_u$. Likely, the subset $V=\cup_u V_u$ is bundle called the vertical subbundle.

What is an example of a tangent bundle to a bundle that we can embed in three space allowing us to depict all its relevant subspace and projections?

Do any topological or geometrical considerations (possibly adding to the case of a principle $F$-bundle) lead us to say that $V_u$ is $T_uE_u$?

Comment: Think about the projection $\pi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ onto the first factor, visualized as a sheet projecting down to a line. The vertical subspaces here are literally vertical lines.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. @Yuan. I speak of the tangent bundle of the principle bundle. What do you call vertical spaces?

Comment: The tangent space to any point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ can canonically be identified with $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself.

Comment: Sure, but this identification forgets about the topology of the bundle and the way the tangent spaces sit against each other. Surely, the tangent bundle of a developable curve is not the union of its tangent lines as they sit in $R^n$. (The tangent line to a point of a curve is off course the gradient line of the curve, translated to this point.) @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Look, I'm only answering the question of why they're called vertical subspaces. I'm quite positive that's the motivating picture, but if it isn't convincing to you then don't use it.

Comment: I apologize, sir.